# border radius specified with multiple parameters does not work

Tags: css

This does not work: (I'm in FireFox 10)

```
  border-radius:  0px, 4px, 4px, 0px;
```

However this does:

```
  border-top-right-radius:  4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:  4px;
```

Comment: That page is ***not*** (in any way whatsoever) related to the W3. At all. ***That*** is W3Schools, named, I can only assume, to *imply* a connection that doesn't exist. The W3's documentation for `border-radius` is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius

Comment: I would, um, probably not use references to w3schools on SO. Just saying, the [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) mafia will "kneecap".

Comment: No one 'hacked' your question, any question, or answer, on Stack Overflow can be edited by others (by design). To see the editors click on the 'edited *n* mins ago' link (after the word 'edited').

Comment: @DavidThomas -The OP was being "funny".

Comment: @Jared: ah? Oh. *whoooosh..!* XD

Comment: If I watched a Joe Pesci movie this morning, does that make me a "wize guy"?

Comment: Read "Snow Crash" by Neal Stephenson if you get a chance..it has mafia and software characters.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put commas between the values in CSS.

The correct answer looks like this:

```
border-radius:  0px 4px 4px 0px;
```

Comment: Technically, the `px` on `0px` are superfluous as well.

Comment: @morph_master_flex - Note as well this syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KbTbC/1/

Comment: I need top left and bottom left...so I still have to specify all 4.

Comment: @morph_master_flex - I know, I just wanted to show you that syntax. It follows `top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left`. I prefer the short syntax where possible, but it's not always possible.